# How to pass an input event to the getter store Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, input, state, vuex, getter

How to pass an input field to the getter?

I'm trying to pass th einput field to the getter as a paramether. How to pass the param to the getter ?

```
<input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search here"
      v-model="search"
      :input=event.target.value"
    />


export const mutations = {
  setProducts(state, data) {
    state.products = data;
  },

export const actions = {
  async getProducts(context) {
    const res = await fetch(...

      context.commit('setProducts', result);
 
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Getters` are basically `computed` properties for the `vuex store`. They take the `state` as their first argument and other `getters` as their second argument. If you want to send something as parameters to the `store` and then perform operations on it, you would have to define an `action` in the `store` and then call that `action` in your component and pass whatever data you need to, to it. `Getters` are meant to access your `vuex state` and `return` them to your component.

Example getter:
`store.js`

```
    //initialize the store
    state: {
      todos: []
    },
    actions: {
      getTodos(/*data from component*/) {
        //set data in todos state and call this action in your component
        state.todos = //data from component
     }
    },
    getters: {
      todos(state) {
        return state.todos;
      }
    }
```

Edit:

Here's how your `component` file would look like.

`component.vue`

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search here"
      v-model="search"
     />

    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { getProducts } from '../store';

    const search = ref('');

    const products = () => {
        getProducts(search.value);
    }
    </script>
```

`store.js`

```
    export const state = () => ({
      products: [],
    });
    
    export const mutations = {
      setProducts(state, data) {
        state.products = data;
      },
    }
    export const actions = {
      async getProducts({ commit }, search) {
        const result = await fetch()
        //perform filter logic here
        commit('setProducts', result);
      },
    }
    export const getters = {
      getProducts(state) {
        return state.products;
      },
    };
```

Make sure to use the getter inside a `computed` property in your component.

Note that this code is based on `Vue 3`

Comment: Yhe main issue is to filter the initial array if true (data passed from the component) and if false need to show the initial array withou filtering. Please see I've edited the initial question code.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added code for your problem, hope this helps.